# display list of buttons in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I've a react code as shown below in which I want to build a `Timezonepicker`. On clicking particular timezone, it should display all list related to it.

**React Code:**

```
const timezones = [moment.tz("America/Toronto").format('z'), 'PT', 'MT', 'CT', 'ET', 'AT', 'NT'];

const Helloworld = (props) => {
    return (
        timezones.map((timezone) => {
            <a onClick = {
                (e) => {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    props.onChange(timezone)
                }
            } > timezone < /a>
        })
    )
}

return(
    <VersionPageHolder>
        {
            <Helloworld onChange={(timezone) => {
                setSelectedTimezone(timezone);
            }}
            />
        }
        <div>{content.title}</div>
        <div>Version List : </div>
        <div>{
            renderElements(selectedTimezone)
        }</div>
    </VersionPageHolder>
)
```

The react code above doesn't show list of `timezones (PT, MT, CT, ET, AT, NT)`. With the code above. At this moment, I am currently seeing:

`timezone timezone timezone timezone timezone timezone`

Comment: Add {brackets} around "timezone" in your Helloworld return, before the closing tag

Comment: @gui3 This works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To inject data inside jsx you should wrap them inside **{}**. Look closely to your map and repair it because you type only **timezone** without **{}**.

```
timezones.map((timezone) => 
    <a onClick = { (e) => { e.preventDefault(); props.onChange(timezone) } } > 
        { timezone } 
    </a>
)
```

Comment: I copied the code but nothing is getting displayed. Am I missing anything ?

Comment: @flash There was also another issue with brackets after arrow. I changed the code, try again :)

Answer (score 0):

To inject a variable in JSX, you'll need use `{}`.

Answer (score 0):

Two issues. One, as pointed out by others, you need curly brackets to use JS in JSX - `{}`. And two, your map function needs to return the `a` tag, which it currently does not. You can fix that by using the `return` statement or just dropping the curly brackets inside the `map`:

```
return (
  <>
    {
      timezones.map((timezone) => 
        <a onClick = {
            (e) => {
                e.preventDefault();
                props.onChange(timezone)
            }
        } > timezone </a>
    )
  }
  </> 
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Two issues one related to React and one related to Javascript.

- First issue related aboud React: You should wrap the variables with curly braces `{}` to display the data, you can check this [doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html#embedding-expressions-in-jsx) for more information. In your code it would be as follows:

> } > {timezone} < /a>

- Second issue related aboud Javascript: When you use [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) always try to return something. In your code it would be as follows with only parenthesis `()` instead of `{}`:

> ```
>     timezones.map((timezone) => (
>         <a onClick = {
>             (e) => {
>                 e.preventDefault();
>                 props.onChange(timezone)
>             }
>         } > {timezone} < /a>
>     ))
> ```

or with curly braces `{}` and `return`:

> ```
>     timezones.map((timezone) => {
>         return <a onClick = {
>             (e) => {
>                 e.preventDefault();
>                 props.onChange(timezone)
>             }
>         } > {timezone} < /a>
>     })
> ```